# working but need to get that piece from mysql

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, lucee

I have the following code which is working as expected,

```
I am editing my question again here
```

This is the loop i have

```
<cfquery name="qry">
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="qrysell">
  SELECT *
  FROM table2
  WHERE SPID=<cfqueryparam value="#Val(qry.SPID)#">
</cfquery>
    
<ul>
    <cfloop query="qrysell">
        <cfquery name="insidequery">
          SELECT SPCPID
          FROM table3
          WHERE SPOID=<cfqueryparam value="#Val(qrysell.SPOID)#">
        </cfquery>
        <li><a href="">#qrysell.Text1# <small>(#qrysell.SPOID#)</small> | #Val(insidequery.RecordCount)#</a></li>
    </cfloop>
</ul>
```

instead all i am trying to do is just bring the loop data in mysql and this is where i am some doubts that how should i do?

i already had a loop like this

```
<cfquery name="qry">
    SELECT * 
      FROM table1 
      left join table2 
        ON table2.SPID = table1.SPID 
      left join table3 
        on table3.SPOID = table2.SPOID 
    </cfquery>
```

i am trying to adjust the code in first block to be directly being generated in the second query and i am bit lost what is wrong i am doing

Comment: I don't totally understand the question. Additional, ideally for performance reasons you should do a join in the first query, so you don't run a separate query call for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: We're pretty good at answering questions in this forum, but the problem is that it's unclear what you're asking.  See this link for how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.column1, sales.salesTotal
FROM table1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(dkid) AS salesTotal, spoid 
    FROM table2 GROUP BY spoid
) sales ON sales.spoid = table1.spid
```

This should return a single query like so:

```
id  |  column1  |  salesTotal
```

Which then you can loop over:

```
<td>
    <ul>
        <cfloop query="qry">
            <li>
                 <a href="#>#column1# <small>(#id#)</small> | #Val(salesTotal)# users</a>
            </li>
        </cfloop>
    </ul>
</td>
```

Is that what you are asking how to do?

Comment: but the join is already in the query, i am doing it, just want to know how can get the data  for that count along with count

Comment: I'm not sure I totally follow, but my query does a JOIN with the count. Essentially salesTotal in mine is like yours with recordCount. You've also modified your question since I posted. Initially you only had two queries but the idea is the same.

Comment: Also, you really don't want to do a query inside of a loop if you can avoid it.

Comment: that is my goal, i want to avoid the inner loop and bring that functionality from mysql and that is where i am stuck, i tried the solution by @leeish but it creates more rows which is wrong, it should be the same number of rows

Comment: I don't know your data well enough, the principle is the same. Join in a select query that returns a count of the rows you want.